# É possivel negar acesso a diretorio e permitir acesso ao arquivo com .htaccess?como?

Tags: apache

Estou tentando fazer um .htaccess para as url's amigáveis porem gostaria de fazer com que as pessoas não conseguissem ver meus diretórios e ao mesmo tempo que os scripts conseguissem acessar os arquivos... é possível fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para que não listem seus diretórios, basta usar esta diretiva:

```
Options -Indexes
```

No `.htaccess` ou na configuração do diretório:

```
<Directory /www/pasta>
   Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

Lembre-se que para usar no `.htaccess` vai depender do `AllowOverride` em uso permitir.

Caso queira bloquear o acesso aos arquivos deste diretório, pode ser mais radical e colocar um .htaccess na pasta com estas condições:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
```

Assim o caminho só servirá pra includes e similares.

> Neste caso, um caminho mais simples é por as pastas de templates e includes fora da raiz do site, por exemplo "ao lado" do `httpdocs`, e não dentro.

Comment: Era exatamente isso, tinha visto varias "soluções na web" mas nada que fazia o que deveria fazer, a maioria das coisas me retornou erro 500, mas isso funcionou certinho :D