# Listagem de pastas do servidor aparece no browser

Tags: apache, linux

Tenho no servidor instalado o `Debian`, `Apache`, `PHP5` e `MySql`.

Ao digitar no browser o endereço de uma pasta, por exemplo, http://www.dominio.com/api, todos as pastas e arquivos são listados.

Como faço para que as pastas e arquivos não sejam listados no browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para que não listem seus diretórios, use esta diretiva:

```
Options -Indexes
```

No .htaccess ou na configuração do diretório:

```
<Directory /www/pasta>
   Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

Fontes:

[Desabilitando a listagem de diretórios no Apache](http://angelitomg.com/blog/desabilitando-a-listagem-de-diretorios-no-apache/)

[É possivel negar acesso a diretorio e permitir acesso ao arquivo com .htaccess?como?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14012/%C3%89-possivel-negar-acesso-a-diretorio-e-permitir-acesso-ao-arquivo-com-htaccessc)

[Proteger pasta contra acesso direto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52930/proteger-pasta-contra-acesso-direto)